# Given $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a$. Given $a_n$ is abscissa of intersection point of $AA_n$ and $Ox$ find $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$. Where $A=\dots$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometry, limits

> Let $\{x_n\}$ define a sequence with the following limit:
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a
> $$ 
>   Let $AA_n$ be a set of straight lines on $XY$ plane each defined by two points $A = (a, a^2)$ and $A_n =(x_n, x_n^2)$. Define a sequence $a_n$ which is obtained by taking the value of abscissa of intersection point of $AA_n$ and $Ox$.
>
> Find:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n
> $$

I've started from trying to graph what the above means from a geometric perspective. Using Desmos I've crafted a [visualization](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zgbmcqrwup) of the sequence and the lines defined in the question section.

From the graph it's crystal clear that the sequence tends to $a\over 2$ which gives:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = {a\over 2}
$$

The problem is that a graph is not a formal proof. How can I formally find the limit of $a_n$ without involving any graphs?

Comment: Write down the expression for $a_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to see the line $AA_n$ is given by
$$
\frac {y_n - a^2}{x_n - a} = \frac {x_n^2 - a^2} {x_n - a} = x_n + a
$$
when $x_n \neq a$ for all $n$. Then setting $y =0$ in the equation above, we solve for $x$, which is just $a_n$, and obtain
$$
\boxed {a_n = a - \dfrac {a^2}{x_n + a}}
$$
whenever $x_n \neq -a$. Under this condition we let $n \to +\infty$ and get the result.

If $x_n = \pm a$ for some $n$, then such $a_n$ actually is not defined. So we assume $|x_n| \neq a$ for all $n$ in the reasoning above.